# Community Promotion Ads - 1H 2011

Tags: discussion, top-7, promotion, community-ads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Community Promotion Ads - 1H 2012](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/814/community-promotion-ads-1h-2012)

#### What in the Wide, Wide World of Sports is Going On Here?

TL;DR -- put images and links in the answers. If they get voted up enough, they will appear on the main site as community promotion ads.

#### But whyyyyyyy?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- cool unix and linux related open source apps
- the site's twitter account
- scripts packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. And to click on it for great justice!

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/541).

Answer (score 17):

[image: Put the fun back into computing. Use Linux, BSD.]

Comment: I cheated, the [original image](http://distrowatch.com/dwres.php?resource=faq) was 170x232.

Answer (score 14):

[image: StackApplet Screenshot]

Comment: StackApplet is a tiny notification icon that sits in your tray and allows you to keep track of your reputation on this and other StackExchange sites. You will receive notifications of comments people post to you as well as reputation and answers to your questions.

Comment: ...and it should run on any version of Linux / Unix (since it's written entirely in Python). I have `.RPM` and `.DEB` packages on the Launchpad page.

Comment: +1 - Lovely stuff.

Answer (score 13):

[image: Follow us on Twitter]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Answer (score 4):

[image: FreeBSD: the power to serve]

Answer (score 3):

[image: FreeBSD]