# Community Promotion Ads - 2013

Tags: discussion, community-ads

As it is December 2012, we are now going to reset our Community Promotion Ads for the new year.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- interesting unix and linux related open source apps
- the site's twitter account
- script packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/1105).

Comment: Which license is required for the images?

Comment: @Martin Pardon? Required in what fashion?

Comment: Would an image from http://www.openbsd.org/art2.html be o.k.? "Most images provided here are copyright by OpenBSD, by Theo de Raadt, or by other members or developers of the OpenBSD group. However, it is our intent that anyone be able to use these images to represent OpenBSD in a positive light"

Comment: If you use it in a positive light, that seems usable, then.

Comment: Nope. See [Should images be accompanied with licensing info?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/101802) and [Please negotiate and make obvious user-favorable license terms for uploaded images](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137714): Uploading them to the SE network makes them available under CC-BY-SA. I can't do that as I'm not the copyright holder.

Comment: @Martin You don't need to upload the image to us in order to use it here.

Comment: See above: "Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)"

Comment: Oh, hey, forgot about that. Alright. Let me double check on all that for you, then.

Comment: @MartinSchröder, since the source site clearly says to "enjoy them and let the world see them," my assumption would be that you can submit them.  If you want a more definitive statement, you'd have to ask them.

Comment: @Jaydles: I asked Theo: No.

Answer (score 118):

[image: Dennis Ritchie Home Page]

Comment: Dennis Ritchie has a lot of historical Unix stuff on his website that he saved over the years from when he was working on it.

Comment: This was an inspired choice; it is particularly apposite for our homepage, thanks for putting it up...

Comment: "The server at bell labs is taking too long to respond" :(

Comment: fantastic. thank you.

Comment: RIP, god bless him

Comment: The link appears to be dead as of 7/1/13, along with everything under `bell-labs.com/who`.

Comment: It's now http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/who/dmr/index.html

Comment: DMR is certainly a hoopy frood, but a little text would improve this "advertisement" enormously.

Comment: His picture is creeping me out...

Comment: @msw In my opinion leaving it contextless leaves it kind of "mystic" -- I think that's probably the reason for the extremely elevated click rates on this advertisement, as well

Answer (score 71):

[image: GNU's Not Unix!]

Answer (score 70):

[image: Vim the editor]

Answer (score 67):

[image: Debian -- The Universal Operating System]

Answer (score 65):

[image: Arch Linux: A simple, lightweight Linux distribution.]

Comment: This is just a rough idea, improvements are welcome: ask me for the XCF file.

Answer (score 37):

[image: Follow us on Twitter]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Answer (score 37):

[image: FreeBSD]

Answer (score 29):

[image: Prioritize. Save time. Stay focused.]

Answer (score 22):

[image: writeLaTeX.com - Free Online LaTeX Editor]

Comment: This is an ad from TeX SX, which may also be useful here. WriteLaTeX is basically Etherpad + LaTeX; free online collaborative editor with an automatic preview of the compiled document. Happy to let the community vote decide - I'm one of the developers of writeLaTeX, so any feedback appreciated, thanks.

Comment: +1: Showed this to one of my coworkers. He loved it.

Answer (score 21):

[image: More than secure - FreeBSD]

Comment: Wait, why are there two FreeBSD ads?

Comment: No idea, I submitted mine months before the other. Also, I rotate the ad through these three images: Secure: http://i.stack.imgur.com/DpB75.png Creation: http://i.imgur.com/gz1Si.png Choice: http://i.imgur.com/FR25D.png These images are based on the official advertising material (edited for the 220x250 size).

Comment: Except the community voted for the first; not to give you a license to roll through any others--those should be submitted separately.

Answer (score 20):

[image: Emacs, the extensible, customizable, self-documenting real-time display editor]

Comment: Emacs is great, but this logo is not well-known enough IMO to stand without a caption (title).

Comment: @LarsH I don't really know how I could edit it such that it still *looks* good.  Besides, that's what the click-through is for.

Comment: The click-through is for finding out what the logo refers to? I don't bother to click on logos I don't recognize. Maybe some people do. Wish I could help you on ideas for how to make a caption look good, but I'm not much of a designer.

Comment: Sorry, edited your post by mistake. @LarsH how about [this](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/1447/22222)?

Answer (score 19):

[image: Enterprise-class Linux]

Answer (score 18):

[image: Fedora Linux]

Answer (score 11):

[image: openSUSE 12.3 is out]

Answer (score 10):

[image: GNU emacs, an extensible, customizable text editor—and more.]

Comment: Posted this version of the emacs logo since it mentions the name.

Comment: I forgot about this one!

Comment: Maybe it's just me, But I frankly couldn't tell what the hell this logo even was until I moused over it. It's stylized to the point of indecipherability.

Answer (score 9):

[image: Linux Mint: from freedom freedom came elegance]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Puppet]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Ubuntu: Linux for human beings]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Linux Mint Debian Edition (LMDE) is a semi-rolling distribution based on Debian Testing.]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Launchpad]

Comment: Many & many tiny or medium programs in every OS, like linux use it, You can see how many programs use it by executing `echo N | yum remove sqlite*`

Answer (score -3):

[image: Launchpad]