# Please link to an explanation from "stats" link for community ads

Tags: discussion, community-ads-meta

I had no idea about community promotion ads. I just clicked on one and was somewhat puzzled.  I went back and hovered over the ad, and discovered that it had "comments" and "stats" links.  I then clicked on [the "stats" link](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/1105) which gave me a vague idea about what I was looking at, but no real explanation.

Could the "stats" page please link to something like [Community Promotion Ads - 2013](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1105/community-promotion-ads-2013) or -- even better -- some sort of general explanation of the concept of community promotion ads?

And / or perhaps the hover links could include an "about" link which would take me directly to the (hereby postulated) FAQ for this topic?